# Want to extract particular value from the response and pass it on to next request

Tags: jmeter

Have the following JSON body fetched from JSON extractor using a expression `$.namespaces[?(@.type=='account_id')].permissions`,

```
Result[0]=
{
    "query_view_only_own": 0,
    "location_view": 1,
    "user_modify_notifications": 1,
    "customcode_edit": 0,
    "link_edit": 0,
    "dictionary_view": 0,
    "study_field_customfield_6385aa2c-f79f-4670-b8b7-9136ebd75ed5": "F",
    "study_field_patientid": "F",
    "study_field_customfield_9bff67fb-f18e-4de1-982c-1798376881b1": "H",
    "study_report_hl7_view_unapproved": 0,
    "customfield_edit": 1,
    "study_push": 1,
    "message_edit": 1,
    "radreport_edit": 0,
    "destination_search_mwl": 0,
    "site_qualify": 1,
    "group_view": 1,
    "hl7_template_edit": 0,
    "study_field_customfield_77bd643b-28fe-4306-b08b-33ea96bfa200": "F",
    "study_merge": 0,
    "route_edit": 1,
    "study_report_delete_approved": 1,
    "site_delete": 0,
    "study_report_view_unapproved": 0,
    "site_edit": 0,
    "terminology_edit": 1,
    "query_view_meta": 1,
    "query_attachment_view": 1,
    "study_report_detail": 1,
    "role_edit": 1,
    "radreport_view_only_own": 0,
    "case_edit": 0,
    "qctask_prioritize": 1,
    "study_duplicate": 0,
    "query_view": 1,
    "study_field_study_description": "F",
    "destination_edit": 1,
    "scanner_view": 0,
    "analytics_view": 1,
    "case_view": 0,
    "validate_view": 0,
    "case_edit_only_own": 0,
    "job_view": 1,
    "hl7_transform_view": 0,
    "ui_json": "",
    "appointment_edit": 0,
    "dicomdata_view": 1,
    "user_modify_others_email": 1,
    "audit_view": 1,
    "study_share_group": 1,
    "account_user_edit": 1,
    "account_view": 1,
    "meeting_view": 1,
    "patient_view": 0,
    "webhook_run": 1,
    "customfield_view": 1,
    "customfield_list": 1,
    "study_download": 1,
    "message_view": 1,
    "radreport_view": 0,
    "study_share_rsna": 0,
    "study_thin": 0,
    "qctask_add": 1,
    "study_browse": 1,
    "study_sync": 0,
    "hl7_message_view": 0,
    "study_delete_image": 0,
    "user_modify_others_pkey": 0,
    "viewer_config": "",
    "study_view": 1,
    "account_user_invite": 1,
    "study_request_view_inbound": 0,
    "study_share_user": 1,
    "qctask_edit": 1,
    "study_field_patient_birth_date": "F",
    "site_view": 0,
    "study_report_hl7_view": 1,
    "study_upload": 1,
    "study_field_customfield_987eb6cd-6e63-4605-812a-06600e721493": "H",
    "study_field_customfield_4b2e868b-2438-4597-a8fd-d639ccff942c": "F",
    "dictionary_edit": 0,
    "route_view": 1,
    "study_clone": 0,
    "study_share_location": 1,
    "location_edit": 1,
    "user_setting_set": 0,
    "role_view": 1,
    "study_status_edit": 0,
    "study_report_delete_unapproved": 0,
    "study_star": 1,
    "user_modify_others_notifications": 0,
    "query_edit": 1,
    "pathology_upload": 1,
    "study_report_delete": 1,
    "channel_activity": 1,
    "study_field_customfield_8d1fbaeb-c9f2-420c-ad53-73ebc5dfb425": "F",
    "destination_search": 0,
    "user_modify_defaults": 1,
    "patient_edit": 0,
    "sharing_rule_edit": 1,
    "study_field_customfield_f3caaa4d-ec29-4148-9055-90ca3594a276": "F",
    "study_approve": 1,
    "node_edit_own": 0,
    "site_user_delete": 0,
    "query_attachment_delete": 1,
    "link_edit_upload": 0,
    "terminology_view": 1,
    "dicomdata_edit": 1,
    "query_add": 1,
    "study_report_upload": 1,
    "study_take": 0,
    "link_view": 0,
    "study_comment_view": 0,
    "customcode_deploy": 0,
    "hl7_transform_edit": 0,
    "qctask_delete": 1,
    "hl7_template_view": 0,
    "webhook_edit": 1,
    "site_user_add": 0,
    "link_direct": 1,
    "study_report_view_only_own": 0,
    "namespace_question": 1,
    "study_search_require_patient_birth_date": 0,
    "node_view": 1,
    "purge_edit": 0,
    "study_request_view": 0,
    "study_edit_unapproved": 1,
    "study_send_status_view": 1,
    "study_comment_edit": 0,
    "study_duplicate_request": 0,
    "case_view_only_own": 0,
    "study_delete": 0,
    "study_report_view": 1,
    "annotation_view": 1,
    "account_user_view": 1,
    "study_field_referring_physician": "F",
    "study_share_share_code": 1,
    "case_delete": 0,
    "study_field_customfield_1fe37b5d-c830-41cd-9beb-06df42c69eb0": "F",
    "study_field_patient_name": "F",
    "study_edit_approved": 1,
    "setting_ip_whitelist": 1,
    "filter_edit_only_own": 0,
    "study_report_hl7_view_approved": 1,
    "location_clone": 0,
    "site_user_view": 0,
    "study_manual_route": 0,
    "query_attachment_add": 1,
    "can_proxy_login": 0,
    "study_move": 0,
    "appointment_view_only_own": 0,
    "study_search_require_patient_sex": 0,
    "query_attachment_delete_only_own": 1,
    "radreport_html_format": 0,
    "study_field_modality": "F",
    "user_view_others_notifications": 0,
    "study_status_view": 0,
    "setting_pacs_config_customized": 1,
    "study_report_view_approved": 1,
    "order_edit": 0,
    "group_clone": 0,
    "annotation_view_only_own": 0,
    "study_share": 1,
    "webhook_view": 1,
    "study_download_viewer": 1,
    "keyimage_view": 1,
    "study_tag": 1,
    "study_request_view_only_own": 0,
    "study_share_email": 0,
    "study_report_upload_unapproved": 0,
    "research_edit": 0,
    "scanner_add": 0,
    "accelerator_edit": 1,
    "qctask_view": 1,
    "study_download_iso": 1,
    "sharing_rule_view": 1,
    "study_edit": 1,
    "scanner_delete": 0,
    "user_request_access": 1,
    "research_view": 0,
    "study_field_customfield_6480baa2-cd2c-4c60-be92-ddcd09675c45": "H",
    "link_edit_pin": 0,
    "annotation_edit_only_own": 1,
    "study_timing_view": 0,
    "site_user_edit": 0,
    "study_field_customfield_2ac756f4-c7be-4bb4-90ed-78e36266ade5": "F",
    "hl7_message_delete": 0,
    "study_request_edit": 0,
    "annotation_edit": 1,
    "study_split": 0,
    "appointment_view": 0,
    "study_audio_play": 0,
    "node_edit": 1,
    "channel_study": 1,
    "role_setting_edit": 1,
    "query_reply": 1,
    "scanner_validate": 1,
    "group_edit": 1,
    "purge_view": 0,
    "query_delete": 1,
    "study_status_tags_ignore_rules": 1,
    "scanner_edit": 0,
    "study_field_accession_number": "F",
    "customcode_view": 0,
    "user_modify_sharecode": 1,
    "study_field_patient_sex": "F",
    "study_field_study_date": "F",
    "study_search_require_patientid": 0,
    "user_edit_shared_filter": 0,
    "patient_merge": 0,
    "viewer3_config": "",
    "study_share_request": 0,
    "accelerator_view": 1,
    "filter_share": 1,
    "user_edit": 1,
    "study_field_customfield_dfb98397-2a6d-4075-a4d0-8684cdcde9d9": "F",
    "study_freeze": 0,
    "study_audio_record": 0,
    "study_search_require_patient_name": 0,
    "node_approve_connect": 1,
    "account_edit": 1,
    "study_share_account": 1,
    "meeting_edit": 0,
    "study_status_manual_edit": 1,
    "node_connect": 1,
    "order_view": 0,
    "validate_edit": 0,
    "keyimage_edit": 1,
    "study_search_require_accession_number": 0,
    "site_add": 0,
    "study_upload_validate": 0,
    "destination_view": 1,
    "study_share_npi": 0,
    "study_report_upload_approved": 1
}
```

What fetch all the `study_field_customfield_` and the corresponding value `"H"` and pass is inside next json request object how to do it in JMeter ?

part of next request JSON is,

```
"study_field_accession_number": "F",
    "study_field_modality": "F",
    "study_field_patientid": "F",
    "study_field_patient_birth_date": "F",
    "study_field_patient_name": "F",
    "study_field_patient_sex": "F",
    "study_field_referring_physician": "F",
    "study_field_study_date": "F",
    "study_field_study_description": "F",
    "study_field_customfield_90eb00fa-ae75-4125-bd03-f8793b2a8ef0": "F",
    "study_field_customfield_fcfca2fe-308d-48ac-80a6-e2f49e313151": "F",
    "study_field_customfield_4420ac5e-6d4f-4b02-8a44-24871f97861b": "H",
    "study_field_customfield_70d1c4de-dbd4-47e5-9f1f-4f3e323e25ed": "H",
    "study_field_customfield_c3243b67-4982-40c5-b5c9-ce64811425e2": "F",
    "study_field_customfield_c3fb12a2-d89b-4427-be45-7c92a9c7ef70": "F",
    "study_field_customfield_89755cc7-8df0-44c4-98bb-6e0767684bd4": "F",
    "study_field_customfield_a46034ac-2bf9-4d9d-a815-20cf86155a37": "H",
    "study_field_customfield_f4095a86-12cf-4482-958d-1a3b012f83be": "F",
    "study_field_customfield_b0ba863e-5f8c-43a6-8890-8afc1af2d460": "F",
    "study_field_customfield_4a41f25b-677e-4f81-bb74-00c54a010833": "F",
    "setting_pacs_config_customized": 1
```

Cannot hardcoded it as `study_field_customfield_4a41f25b-677e-4f81-bb74-00c54a010833` they keep on changing for every other request.

I tried with following but it is giving me blank value,

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def extractedValue = vars.get("pre_responseJSON");

def customeField = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(extractedValue).permissions.findAll{
        it.getKey().startsWith('study_field_customfield_')
        };

log.info(":"+customeField+":");
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `permissions` object in your variable, you should remove it from the filtering code snippet like:

```
def customeField = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(extractedValue).findAll{
    it.getKey().startsWith('study_field_customfield_')
}
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)