# JDBC and HTTP request on multiple threads

Tags: jmeter

I have the following structure:

> > Thread

> > JDBC request which takes top 100 resuts from a table and concatenate them with ',' separator (e.g. "1,2,3,4,5")

> > DELETE call which is using the variable created by the JDBC request which include those IDs with "," separator.

The things work on 1 thread, but the problem occur once I increase the threads. The problem, that arise with 2 threads, for example, is that the JDBC request is getting executed 2 times and gets the same IDs, then the DELETE call is executed 2 times - first time is successfull, because the call is valid, but on the next call (user 2/2) it fails, because those ids are already deleted.

I'm searching for any ideas how that can be solved.

Tried with "Once Only Controller", but the threads are going down up to e.g. 100, and then going down and for the main request I see there is only 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "top 100" you should go for [LIMIT and OFFSET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76507097/want-to-extract-particular-value-from-the-response-and-pass-it-on-to-next-reques/76507253#76507253)

As the `LIMIT` you can use 100 and as the `OFFSET` you can use current thread number multiplied by 100

It can be achieved using i.e. [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) and [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) functions combination

```
${__jexl3(${__threadNum} * 100,)}
```

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Comment: Thank you, that solved the big issue, but I still see 404 for some resources when I use more threads. Not sure why that happen, any idea? I see that sometimes there are 2 delete requests with same values. The one is processed by the thread #5, the other from thread #6.

Comment: I see that as long as it is JDBC first and then the request - there is no problem. But at some point with many threads the requests and JDBC requests are intertwined and this seems to cause the request to pass first before the JDBC request with the old data and that lead to 404.

Comment: It happens like:
JDBC request 1-1
DELETE request 1-1
JDBC request 1-2
JDBC request 1-3
JDBC request 1-4
JDBC request 1-5
DELETE request 1-1 - fail here, because it did that already and there's no JDBC with fresh data

Comment: I've added 'Synchronizing Timer' as a child to both requests and seems like that solved the minor issue! Thanks!